# Debian Livestick with additional software

Tags: linux, debian, software-installation, live-usb

I've got a bunch of USB-Sticks with Debian for teaching young students HTML, PHP and MySQL alongside Linux. Because it has been decided (not by me) that I'm not allowed to install Linux on our school pcs I'm using Livesticks (which work great).
My problem is, that our internet connection is *very* bad, and it's not possible to download & install MySQL, Apache, etc every time.
The Live-Sticks otherwise seem to be the way to go for me, because of the reset. This way the students can't save stuff on the sticks for tests, etc, or alter them in other ways.
I thought about setting up a repository server, so we can download every package we need from it. Sadly, this isn't an option because our system administrator doesn't allow additional PC's in the network.

So here is my question:
Is it somehow possible for me to install the needed packages (permanently) on the Livesticks? I would prefer not using XAMPP.

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking for the same thing and this question is the only thing related I found.

Your problem may be solved with LinuxLive_USB_Creator (read as well: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LinuxLive_USB_Creator)

Download can be found here: http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/supported-linuxes

You probably have to "install" the livesticks again and this time include a certain amount of space on the memory-stick(s) as "persistent", so it can be used to save changes like your additional packages.

I haven' t tried it myself yet, but it looks promising.

Easier (with respect to the time invested into creating and editing several Live-sticks) would be to edit the ISO you use. But I don' t know how that would work.

Good Luck!